# How to generate server-sent events for status change notifications in a Python web app?

Tags: python, cherrypy, server-sent-events

I have a web app written in CherryPy: a user uploads a file, then some lengthy operation begins, passing through several stages. I want notifications for these stages to be pushed to all the connected clients. But I don't know how to communicate between processes. I guess I would have to launch the lengthy operation in a separate process, but then I don't know how to pass the "advanced to stage N" messages to the "server-sending function".

Conceptually, it would be something like this:

SSEtest.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep
import cherrypy


def lengthy_operation(name, stream):
    for stage in range(10):
        print(f'stage {stage}... ', end='')
        sleep(2)
        print('done')
    print('finished')


class SSETest():

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return Path('SSEtest.html').read_text()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def upload(self, file):
        name = file.filename.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
        lengthy_operation(name, file.file)
        return 'OK'

    @cherrypy.expose
    def stage(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream;charset=utf-8'

        def lengthy_operation():
            for stage in range(5):
                yield f'data: stage {stage}... \n\n'
                sleep(2)
                yield 'data: done\n\n'
            yield 'data: finished\n\n'

        return lengthy_operation()

    stage._cp_config = {'response.stream': True, 'tools.encode.encoding': 'utf-8'}


cherrypy.quickstart(SSETest())
```

SSEtest.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SSE Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>SSE Test</h1>
<div>
    <form id="load_file_form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="load_file">Load a file: </label>
        <input type="file" id="load_file" name="load_file">
        <progress max="100" value="0" id="progress_bar"></progress>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="status_messages">
<h3>Stages:</h3>
</div>

<script>
    const load_file = document.getElementById('load_file');
    const progress_bar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');

    function update_progress_bar(event) {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            progress_bar.value = Math.round((event.loaded/event.total)*100);
        }
    }

    load_file.onchange = function (event) {
        let the_file = load_file.files[0];
        let formData = new FormData();
        let connection = new XMLHttpRequest();

        formData.append('file', the_file, the_file.name);

        connection.open('POST', 'upload', true);
        connection.upload.onprogress = update_progress_bar;
        connection.onload = function (event) {
            if (connection.status != 200) {
                alert('Error! ' + event);
            }
        };

        connection.send(formData);
    };

    const status_messages = document.getElementById("status_messages");
    const sse = new EventSource("stage");

    sse.onopen = function (event) {
        let new_message = document.createElement("p");
        new_message.innerHTML = "Connection established: " + event.type;
        status_messages.appendChild(new_message);
    };

    sse.onmessage = function (event) {
        let new_message = document.createElement("p");
        new_message.innerHTML = event.data;
        status_messages.appendChild(new_message);
    };

    sse.onerror = function(event) {
        let new_message = document.createElement("p");
        if (event.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            new_message.innerHTML = "Connections closed";
        } else {
            new_message.innerHTML = "Error: " + event.type;
        }
        status_messages.appendChild(new_message);
    };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need `lengthy_operation()` to be called only once, when the file is uploaded. And the messages generated by it to be sent to all the clients. Now it works with the local function, which is not what I want. How can I use the outer function and pass its messages into the `stage()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want notifications for these stages to be pushed to all the connected clients.

I suspect in the end you will want more control than that, but I will answer your question as it was asked. Later, you may want to build on the example below and filter the broadcasted notifications based on the user's session, or based on a certain starting timestamp, or some other relevant concept.

Each "connected client" is effectively hanging on a long-running request to `/stage` which the server will use to stream [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Event_stream_format) to the client. In your example, each client will begin that request immediately and leave it open until the server terminates the stream. You can also close the stream from the client using [`close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource/close) on the `EventSource`.

## Basic Solution

You asked how to have the `/stage` handler broadcast or mirror its events to all of the currently-connected clients. There are many ways you could accomplish this, but in a nutshell you want the `lengthy_operation` function to either post events to all `/stage` handler readers or to a persistent shared location from which all `/stage` handlers read. I will show a way to encapsulate the first idea described above.

Consider a generic stream event class that serializes to `data: <some message>`:

```py
class StreamEvent:
    def __init__(self, message: str) -> bytes:
        self.message = message

    def serialize(self) -> str:
        return f'data: {self.message}\n\n'.encode('utf-8')
```

and a more specific derived case for file-related stream events:

```py
class FileStreamEvent(StreamEvent):
    def __init__(self, message: str, name: str):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.name = name

    def serialize(self) -> bytes:
        return f'data: file: {self.name}: {self.message}\n\n'.encode('utf-8')
```

You can create an extremely primitive publish/subscribe type of container where `/stage` can then subscribe listeners and `lengthy_operation()` can publish `StreamEvent` instances to all listeners:

```py
class StreamSource:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listeners: List[Queue] = []

    def put(self, event: StreamEvent):
        for listener in self.listeners:
            listener.put_nowait(event)

    def get(self):
        listener = Queue()
        self.listeners.append(listener)
        try:
            while True:
                event = listener.get()
                yield event.serialize()
        finally:
            self.listeners.remove(listener)
```

In `StreamSource.get()`, you likely want to create an end case (e.g. check for a "close" or "finish" event) to exit from the generic `while True` and you likely want to set a timeout on the blocking `Queue.get()` call. But for the sake of this example, I kept everything basic.

Now, `lengthy_operation()` just needs a reference to a `StreamSource`:

```py
def lengthy_operation(events: StreamSource, name: str, stream: BinaryIO):
    for stage in range(10):
        events.put(FileStreamEvent(f'stage {stage}: begin', name))
        sleep(2)
        events.put(FileStreamEvent(f'stage {stage}: end', name))
    events.put(FileStreamEvent('finished', name))
```

`SSETest` can then provide a shared instance of `StreamSource` to each `lengthy_operation()` call and `SSETest.stage()` can use `StreamSource.get()` to register a listener on this shared instance:

```py
class SSETest:
    _stream_source: StreamSource = StreamSource()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return Path('SSETest.html').read_text()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def upload(self, file):
        name = file.filename.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
        lengthy_operation(self._stream_source, name, file.file)
        return 'OK'

    @cherrypy.expose
    def stage(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
        def stream():
            yield from self._stream_source.get()
        return stream()

    stage._cp_config = {'response.stream': True}
```

This is a complete<sup>[1]</sup> example of how to resolve your immediate question but you will most likely want to adapt this as you work closer to the final user experience you probably have in mind.

[1]: I left out the imports for readability, so here they are:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep
from typing import BinaryIO, List
import cherrypy
```

## Follow-on Exit Conditions

Since you are using `cherrypy.quickstart()`, in the minimal viable solution above you will have to forcefully exit the `SSETest` service as I did not assume any graceful "stop" behaviors for you. The first solution explicitly points this out but offers no solution for the sake of readability.

Let's look at a couple ways to provide some initial graceful "stop" conditions:

### Add a stop condition to `StreamSource`

First, at least add a reasonable stop condition to `StreamSource`. For instance, add a `running` attribute that allows the `StreamSource.get()` `while` loop to exit gracefully. Next, set a reasonable `Queue.get()` timeout so the loop can periodically test this `running` attribute between processing messages. Next, ensure at least some relevant CherryPy bus messages trigger this stop behavior. Below, I have rolled all of this behavior into the `StreamSource` class but you could also register a separate application level CherryPy plugin to handle calling into `StreamSource.stop()` rather than making `StreamSource` a plugin. I will demonstrate what that looks like when I add a separate signal handler.

```py
class StreamSource(plugins.SimplePlugin):
    def __init__(self, bus: wspbus.Bus):
        super().__init__(bus)
        self.subscribe()
        self.running = True
        self.listeners: List[Queue] = []

    def graceful(self):
        self.stop()

    def exit(self):
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def put(self, event: StreamEvent):
        for listener in self.listeners:
            listener.put_nowait(event)

    def get(self):
        listener = Queue()
        self.listeners.append(listener)
        try:
            while self.running:
                try:
                    event = listener.get(timeout=1.0)
                    yield event.serialize()
                except Empty:
                    pass
        finally:
            self.listeners.remove(listener)
```

Now, `SSETest` will need to initialize `StreamSource` with a bus value since the class is now a `SimplePlugin`:

```py
    _stream_source: StreamSource = StreamSource(cherrypy.engine)
```

You will find that this solution gets you much closer to what you likely want in terms of user experience. Issue a keyboard interrupt and CherryPy will begin stopping the system, but the first graceful keyboard interrupt will not publish a `stop` message, for that you need to send a second keyboard interrupt.

### Add a SIGINT handler to capture keyboard interrupts

Due to the way `cherrypy.quickstart` works with signal handlers, you may then want to register a [`SIGINT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGINT) handler as a CherryPy-compatible [`SignalHandler`](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.0/refman/process/plugins/signalhandler.html#cherrypy.process.plugins.SignalHandler) plugin to gracefully stop the `StreamSource` at the first keyboard interrupt.

Here is an example:

```py
class SignalHandler(plugins.SignalHandler):
    def __init__(self, bus: wspbus.Bus, sse):
        super().__init__(bus)
        self.handlers = {
            'SIGINT': self.handle_SIGINT,
        }
        self.sse = sse

    def handle_SIGINT(self):
        self.sse.stop()
        raise KeyboardInterrupt()
```

Note that in this case I am demonstrating a generic application level handler which you can then configure and initialize by altering your startup `cherrypy.quickstart()` logic as follows:

```py
sse = SSETest()
SignalHandler(cherrypy.engine, sse).subscribe()
cherrypy.quickstart(sse)
```

For this example, I expose a generic application `SSETest.stop` method to encapsulate the desired behavior:

```py
class SSETest:
    _stream_source: StreamSource = StreamSource(cherrypy.engine)

    def stop(self):
        self._stream_source.stop()
```

## Wrap-up analysis

I am **not** a CherryPy user and I only started looking at it for the first time yesterday just to answer your question, so I will leave "CherryPy best practices" up to your discretion.

In reality, your problem is a very generic combination of the following Python questions:

1. how can I implement a simple publish/subscribe pattern? (answered with `Queue`);
2. how can I create an exit condition for the subscriber loop? (answered with `Queue.get()`'s `timeout` parameter and a `running` attribute)
3. how can I influence the exit condition with keyboard interrupts? (answered with a CherryPy-specific signal handler, but this merely sits on top of concepts you will find in Python's built in [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module)

You can solve all of these questions in many ways and some lean more toward generic "Pythonic" solutions (my preference where it makes sense) while others leverage CherryPy-centric concepts (and that makes sense in cases where you want to augment CherryPy behavior rather than rewrite or break it).

As an example, you could use CherryPy bus messages to convey stream messages, but to me that entangles your application logic a bit too much in CherryPy-specific features, so I would probably find a middle ground where you handle your application features generically (so as not to tie yourself to CherryPy) as seen in how my `StreamSource` example uses a standard Python `Queue` pattern. You could choose to make `StreamSource` a plugin so that it can respond to certain CherryPy bus messages directly (as I show above), or you could have a separate plugin that knows to call into the relevant application-specific domains such as `StreamSource.stop()` (similar to what I show with `SignalHandler`).

Last, all of your questions are great, but they have all likely been answered before on SO as generic Python questions, so while I am tying the answers here to your CherryPy problem space I also want to help you (and future readers) realize how to think about these particular problems more abstractly beyond CherryPy.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete, thorough and well written answer. It helped me a lot. For me, the missing ingredient was the Queue class -- I had started to roll my own async FIFO queue, with threads/events etc. It was woking (sort of), but your solution is much more elegant. And Pythonic.

Comment: One more thing, though: Both with my handmade queue, and with yours, when I try to stop the CherryPy server with Ctrl-C (as I always do), it doesn't exit gracefully. I have to press Ctrl-C several times, and it gives some error message. Can this be avoided? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, you mentioned some enhancements. A concise answer is greatly appreciated -- but, as you anticipated, now I want more. :) Can you point me to a more developed example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Amenhotep, I will edit my original answer to clarify these issues by addressing them individually at the end of the answer. When you read my updated answer (above) you will most likely see my original answer already hinted at these solutions (in brief) but I did not add them because they are not related to the original question. I think the other questions you are asking are better addressed in follow-up questions so others coming from search engines can find each answer as an isolated example.

Comment: Hi Amenhotep, check the updated answer now to see solutions to all of your remaining problems. You will likely see what I mean in my comment above -- it's a bit too "wrong" to slam this much in one question. If you run into additional issues you should post more SO questions with minimal(-ish) working examples like you did here. I am sure someone will answer.

EDIT: I hope my answer above inspires you to try to create and solve examples outside of CherryPy when you run into these general issues as the base concepts are not (at their heart) CherryPy-centric.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey, your answer is like a little manual. It contains lots of good information and advice and it really helps me and other people understand how things work. One solution I had tried is indeed too much tied to the CherryPy pus/sub bus -- I read the code there and tried to adapt it to my needs: https://gist.github.com/ingoogni/a7f7c0fed9e96b3545e9a8c6139d80b0. But I like more your solution, because it is generic. Thanks again for all the explanations and the patience to write such a clear and well documented answer (and beautiful Python code). :)

Comment: Awesome, great to hear the ideas came across clearly for you, and thanks for posting a question about SSE. The SSE bit caught my eye because I had only used websockets for long running client connections in the past. Reading up on SSE standards was enlightening. The unidirectional behavior is a great fit for some use cases. PS: Make sure as you work forward from the solution I showed that client listeners are trimmed as they disconnect and/or add a timeout mechanism for them if that's not reliable (I didn't experiment enough with CherryPy to see what happens after your client calls close).